# How to build example Tango Apps in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

On the Tango Area Learning guide, https://developers.google.cn/tango/apis/unity/unity-howto-area-learning

It is said that after importing the Tango SDK, in the asset folder the area learning app can be built. However I searched but didn't find a way to perform this step. If I want to build an app in the asset folder, what is the recommended way to do so?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build the example **Area Learning** Tango app (Steps in `Unity` after importing the Tango SDK):

> From `Project` inspector (where you see your assets) > **TangoSDK > Examples > Scenes**.
>   Double click the `AreaLearning` scene.
>   Connect your Tango device via `USB` and click **File > Build and Run**.